# Can I convert an Odoo browse object to JSON

Tags: python, json, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm trying to integrate `reactjs` with `Odoo`, and successfully created components. Now my problem is that I cant get the JSON via odoo. The odoo programmer has to write special api request to make this happen. This is taking more time and code repetitions are plenty.

I tried may suggestions and none worked.

Is there a better way to convert the `browse objects`, that `odoo` generate, to `JSON` ?

Note: Entirely new to python and odoo, please forgive my mistakes, if any mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will help you:

Step 1: Create js that runs reqiest to `/example_link`

Step 2: Create controller who listens that link `@http.route('/example_link', type="json")`

Step 3: return from that function json `return json.dumps(res)` where res is python dictionary and also dont forget to import json.

Thats all, it's not very hard, hope I helped you, good luck.

Comment: Your saying about python dictionary, he's asking about browse objects. Is there a way handle browse objects.

Comment: In this case you can use just js-odoo api and get odoo objects, you can make record browse, search and etc. I dont see problem here

Comment: is there any tutorial or example for this ??